# fminsearch multiple parameters matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, arguments, fminsearch

I'm trying to use fminsearch with multiple parameters but I can't seem to even get it working with two. I've also tried using optimization tool in matlab but then I get:

```
Optimization running.
Error running optimization.
Not enough input arguments.
```

What i do:

```
fval = fminsearch(@g,[1 1])
```

The function g looks like this:

```
function r=g(x,y)
   r=x.^3+3*x*y.^2+12*x*y;
end
```

but i get this:

```
Error using g (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fminsearch (line 190)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `g` takes two inputs, `x` and `y`, however you supply `fminsearch` one input, the vector `[1 1]`. You need to rewrite it so that `fminsearch` only needs a single vector as input, but then that vector is split into two numbers to input into `g`.

```
fminsearch(@(v) g(v(1),v(2)),[1 1])
```

This makes an anonymous function that takes a vector as input (`v`) and then uses the first element (`v(1)`) as the first input to `g`, and the second element as the second input.